# Really confused on how constraints work in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, xcode9

Could someone please explain how constraints work in Xcode 9 (Swift), I'm new to programming and I've spent literally 20 hours trying to figure out how constraints work, but when I try it in Xcode, its always in different places on different devices. My goal is to learn how to keep everything the same on all devices.

Am I suppose to set a different constraints for all devices? If not what is the best practice to use when setting constraints?

I want to thank everyone who has read this and I hope this post helps out beginners also!

Happy coding, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Auto Layout dynamically calculates the size and position of all the
>   views in your view hierarchy, based on constraints placed on those
>   views. For example, you can constrain a button so that it is
>   horizontally centered with an Image view and so that the button’s top
>   edge always remains 8 points below the image’s bottom. If the image
>   view’s size or position changes, the button’s position automatically
>   adjusts to match.
>
> This constraint-based approach to design allows you to build user
>   interfaces that dynamically respond to both internal and external
>   changes.

Read all about Auto Layout and constraints at Apples Guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1). There are four different sections that will walk you through the approach:

- Understanding Auto Layout
- Auto Layout Without Constraints
- Anatomy of a Constraint
- Working with Constraints in Interface Builder

Comment: thank you, will take a look

Comment: Pretty sure auto layout is bugged for xCode 9 with collectionViews inside viewControllers - just a heads up if anyone else is experiencing this problem.

Comment: @Torewin, thanks for comment. If you´re experiencing bugs, file a bug to Apple so that they can fix it (:

Comment: @RashwanL I already filed it! It was a duplicate so they are aware of the issue...just in case other people were beating their head on the desk with xCode 9 and similar issues or wait for 9.1 before you upgrade if possible!

Comment: @Torewin, good to hear. Thanks for the info.